# PyQt5 ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qt-designer

Since yesterday I'm facing this issue I can't solve by myself. 
Can anyone please suggest a solution ?

```
File "C:/Myproj_python/pertesCVS.py", line 67, in recupVariables
    Eon1 = float((self.Eon1_lineEdit.text()))
```

As shown in the code, I'm importing a GUI called `pertesCVSUI` parametres generated by Qt designer.

In the method defined as `RecupeVariables` I'm trying to store as variables what the user writes in some `QlineEdits` and to do calculation on those float values in the method defined as `fitenergy`.

```
import numpy as np
import pertesCVSUI
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class PertesCVS(pertesCVSUI.Ui_PertesCVS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # super(PertesCVS, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(parent)
        self.recupVariables()
        self.btnstate()
        self.fitenergy()

    def setupUi(self, parent):
        super(PertesCVS, self).setupUi(parent)

        # setup validators
        self.Eon1_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Eon2_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Eon3_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ion1_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ion2_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ion3_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))

        self.Eoff1_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Eoff2_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Eoff3_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ioff1_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ioff2_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Ioff3_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))

        self.Vcc_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Imax_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Fd_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Mod_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Rdson_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Dc_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))
        self.Tf_lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 3))

        # setup connection        
        self.calculate.clicked.connect(self.recupVariables)
        self.radioButton1.toggled.connect(self.btnstate)
        self.radioButton2.toggled.connect(self.btnstate)

    def btnstate(self):
        if self.radioButton1.isChecked():
            self.Mod_lineEdit.hide()
            self.label_19.hide()
            self.Dc_lineEdit.show()
            self.label_22.show()
        else:
            self.Mod_lineEdit.show()
            self.Dc_lineEdit.hide()
            self.label_22.hide()
            self.label_19.show()

    def recupVariables(self):
        Eon1 = float((self.Eon1_lineEdit.text()))
        Eon2 = float((self.Eon2_lineEdit.text()))
        Eon3 = float((self.Eon3_lineEdit.text()))
        Ion1 = float((self.Ion1_lineEdit.text()))
        Ion2 = float((self.Ion2_lineEdit.text()))
        Ion3 = float((self.Ion3_lineEdit.text()))
        Eoff1 = float((self.Eoff1_lineEdit.text()))
        Eoff2 = float((self.Eoff2_lineEdit.text()))
        Eoff3 = float((self.Eoff3_lineEdit.text()))
        Ioff1 = float((self.Ioff1_lineEdit.text()))
        Ioff2 = float((self.Ioff2_lineEdit.text()))
        Ioff3 = float((self.Ioff3_lineEdit.text()))

        Imax = (self.Imax_lineEdit.text())
        Fd = (self.Fd_lineEdit.text())

    def fitenergy(self):
        ##Energy on
        Aon = np.array([[1, Ion1, Ion1 * Ion1], [1, Ion2, Ion2 * Ion2],
                        [1, Ion3, Ion3 * Ion3]])  ## the error appears here

        Aon_inv = np.linalg.inv(Aon)
        *strong
        text *
        Bon = np.array([Eon1, Eon2, Eon3])

        xon = np.linalg.solve(Aon_inv, Bon)
        ##Energy_off
        Aoff = np.array(
            [[1, Ioff1, Ioff1 * Ioff1], [1, Ioff2, Ioff2 * Ioff2], [1, Ioff3, Ioff3 * Ioff3]])

        Aoff_inv = np.linalg.inv(Aoff)

        Boff = np.array([Eon1, Eon2, Eon3])

        xoff = np.linalg.solve(Aoff_inv, Boff)
        ###
        xon_T = np.transpose(xon)
        xoff_T = np.transpose(xoff)
        print(xon_T, xoff_T)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
ui = PertesCVS(main_widget)
main_widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: show complete error message

Comment: Why do not you use QDoubleSpinBox instead of QLineEdit ?, probably some QLineEdit this empty, and the empty text can not be converted to floating.

Comment: My complete error message is : 
  File "C:/Myproj_python/pertesCVS.py", line 67, in recupVariables
    Eon1 = float((self.Eon1_lineEdit.text()))

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @Felahi.M you have an empty QLineEdit, since the error message is always: `... could not convert string to float: SOME_VALUE`, and in your case SOME_VALUE does not show what indicates that the text is empty.

Comment: @Felahi.M 
Look at this answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929983/6622587

Comment: @eyllanesc well it's empty because values are put in the GUI that does not show up as there is errors

Comment: @Felahi.M As I told you instead of using QLineEdit use QDoubleSpinBox that are designed for that specific task.

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your answer, i will give it a try and come back to you.